# botocore.exceptions.ClientError when trying to access S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to upload a file to a subfolder in an S3 bucket.  I know this question is similar to others.  However, the EC2 instance, from which this script will be run, ostensibly has the following S3 permissions defined in CloudFormation:

```
                  - s3:Get*
                  - s3:List*
                  - s3:PutObject
```

My management doesn't want me keeping keys or other credentials on the instance, so I'm trying to use the IAM role assigned to the instance.

The script I'm trying to run is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader
import json
from glom import glom
from pathlib import Path

# Open the file and load the file
DIR = '/apps/dr-automation/current/config'
filePath = Path(f'{DIR}/stop_config.yaml')
if filePath.is_file():
    with open(filePath) as f:
        stopData = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)

stateless_mp = glom(stopData,'sequence.stateless')
dbclusters_mp = glom(stopData,'sequence.dbclusters')
zkclusters_mp = glom(stopData,'sequence.zkclusters')
shared_mp = glom(stopData,'sequence.shared')
bootstrap_mp = glom(stopData,'sequence.bootstrap')

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
myBucket = s3.Bucket('us-east-1-usge1prod-dr-automation')
with open('./config/stop_config.yaml', 'rb') as data:
    myBucket.upload_fileobj(data, 'config/stop_config.yaml')
```

The script works as intended up to where it tries to access the S3 bucket.  The error output I'm getting is:

```
# python3 stop.py
s3.Bucket(name='us-gov-east-1-usge1prod-dr-automation')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stop.py", line 29, in <module>
    myBucket.upload_fileobj(data, 'config/stop_config.yaml')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 581, in bucket_upload_fileobj
    Callback=Callback, Config=Config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 539, in upload_fileobj
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 106, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 265, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 126, in __call__
    return self._execute_main(kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 150, in _execute_main
    return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/s3transfer/upload.py", line 692, in _main
    client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=body, **extra_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 719, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the time on the machine correct? The error suggests the creds that are being obtained are incorrect somehow.

Comment: The time appears to be correct -- it's set to UTC and is precisely 7 hours ahead of my local time.

Comment: Can you check that your credentials work outside of the script. From the same shell the python script is invoked, try this `aws sts get-caller-identity`, and then `aws s3 ls` this will show us that the creds work, then if that works, use boto3 and just get a list of buckets and make sure that works. The error you are getting is an authentication issue, and not a permission issue. So before we move on to permissions, lets ensure the creds work.

Comment: The commands listed above work if I specify a region={REGION_Name} parameter.